# Fresh package install from yarn 3 (from a brand new repo) won't populate node_modules folder

Tags: yarnpkg

Recently i ran into package issues using yarn 1.22.
Got suggestions to use yarn 3 and i did it in an existing view, and yarn 3 does run better.

Node v16.16.0, MacOS

So i submitted the new package.json and yarn.lock and want to test it in a new view.
The steps are:

```
git clone
cd myApp
yarn -v // still 1.22
yarn set version 3.6.4
yarn -v // now 3.6.4
yarn install
no errors, but no node_modules generated in the end.
```

This is the "yarn install" log

```
➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step
➤ YN0002: │ myApp@workspace:. doesn't provide @types/express (pd07d1), requested by express-jwt-authz
➤ YN0000: │ Some peer dependencies are incorrectly met; run yarn explain peer-requirements <hash> for details, where <hash> is the six-letter p-prefixed code
➤ YN0000: └ Completed
➤ YN0000: ┌ Fetch step
➤ YN0013: │ yallist@npm:4.0.0 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched f
➤ YN0013: │ yaml@npm:2.3.1 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from
➤ YN0013: │ yargs-parser@npm:21.1.1 can't be found in the cache and will be fet
➤ YN0013: │ yargs@npm:17.6.2 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched fr
➤ YN0013: │ yocto-queue@npm:0.1.0 can't be found in the cache and will be fetch
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 1s 829ms
➤ YN0000: ┌ Link step
➤ YN0000: │ ESM support for PnP uses the experimental loader API and is therefore experimental
➤ YN0007: │ aws-crt@npm:1.18.0 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ core-js-pure@npm:3.26.1 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ @datadog/native-appsec@npm:4.0.0 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ @datadog/native-metrics@npm:2.0.0 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ @datadog/pprof@npm:3.2.0 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ protobufjs@npm:7.2.5 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ cpu-features@npm:0.0.9 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ dd-trace@npm:4.16.0 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ ssh2@npm:1.14.0 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 17s 368ms
➤ YN0000: Done with warnings in 19s 392ms
```

Any suggestions pls ?

Answer (score 0):

ok .yarnrc.yaml needs this line

```yaml
nodeLinker: node-modules
```

Now the real solution is, yarn 3 should display proper message indicating the yaml file change.